What is the recommended way to connect to Databricks from Apache NiFi
We have been using Apache NiFi to connect to Databricks. While upgrading to the DBR 14.3   and Nifi to 1.27 we realized that SelectHiveQL and SelectHive3QL  processors are deprecated.
What is the recommended way to get data out of Databricks using NiFi, without having to write my own version of HiveConnectionPool ?
Thank you.

Turns out you can use the regular ExecuteSQLRecord or ExecuteSQL processors to query Databricks database.
This is what my config looks like:
JDBC Driver: DatabricksJDBC42.jar
JVM : OpenJDK 17
NiFi : 1.24.0
Create a DBCPConnectionPool controller with the JDBC URL set to
jdbc:databricks://my-host:443/default;transportMode=http;ssl=1;httpPath=sql/protocolv1/o/459338203923432/<my DB cluster>;AuthMech=3;EnableArrow=0;UID=token;PWD=my-api-token


Don't forget to send the Max Lifetime of a connection to 15 minutes or a smaller value.
Once the this controlled is enabled you can use it in ExecuteSQLRecord processor
So configure that


